# Auto zoom out and view all markers in gmaps4rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

At present when a new marker is added to the map, it will automatically zoom into that new location.

How can I configure gmaps4rails to respond to a button that will automatically zoom out to view all the markers on the map? as below:

[image]

The configuration I have for rendering is:

```
  allLocations = root.table.rows(".selected").data()
  $('#multi_markers').map ->
    handler = Gmaps.build("Google")
    handler.buildMap
      internal:
        id: "multi_markers"
    , ->
      for aLocation in allLocations
        markers = handler.addMarkers([
          {
            lat: aLocation[9]
            lng: aLocation[10]
          }
        ])
      handler.bounds.extendWith markers
      handler.fitMapToBounds()
      return
```

*Note this is pertaining to gmaps4rails not simply gmaps*

Comment: @Substantial That is for the Maps, I am using gmaps4rails

Answer (score 0):

after handler.buildMap you can tell set a default zoom like this:

> handler.buildMap({ provider: { zoom: 15, center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127, -74.00030), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}, internal: {id: 'map'}}

Here assign the latitude: 40.7127 longitude: -74.00030 and zoom: 15. The rest is type of map and can be left out